# Clear @Html.TextArea

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I want to add TextArea value in database after that I want to clear the TextArea. How can I achieve this?

**View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ResearcherMessage", "Researcher", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ResearcherMessageDiv" }))
{
        @Html.TextArea("MessageTextArea", new { @class = "messageTextArea" })
        <br />
        <input id="AddMessageSubmit" type="submit" value="Add Message" />
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amend your AjaxOptions object to include the following property:

```
OnSuccess="Done"
```

Then define a JavaScript function with that name that does what you need, for example:

```
function Done() { 
    document.getElementById("MessageTextArea").innerHTML = '';
}
```